# Rails unusual statement: where( ).first_or_create( )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Ryan's [Omniauth with Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised?autoplay=true) railscast. A part of the code was:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.username = auth.info.nickname
    end
  end
end
```

I am scratching my head with where().first_or_create do. What does this code exactly do?

My guess is that where() statement is applied to class User. But how does Rails know that it is equivalent to `User.where(:provider => "provider_id passed by auth", :uid => "uid passed by auth")`?

My guess is that it yields a collection, then if collection is empty, then create a new instance `user` and assign new attributes. Else pick the first instance and reassign attributes.

Are my guesses correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's slice this up into parts.

**auth.slice(:provider, :uid)**

auth is a hash that contains a :provider and :uid keys. calling .slice to auth returns a new hash with only these as keys. ie

```
auth = { provider: 'foo', uid: 'bar', some_other_key: 'blah' }
new_hash = auth.slice(:provider, :uid) # { provider: 'foo', uid: 'bar' }
```

**first_or_create**

is the equivalent of `find_or_create_by`.  You can read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_create) and see that it searches for any record that matched the options passed to `where`.  If no record is found, it tries to create a record with those options as attributes.

the block passed

```
user.provider = auth.provider
user.uid = auth.uid
user.username = auth.info.nickname
```

actually only needs the last line.  The first 2 lines are redundant because it is in the where option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain how the where() statement works without specifying which attribute is associated with which value? Also, I am not sure if your last statement is correct. What if there's no instance of User created before?

Comment: i've updated my answer with an example. `auth.slice` returns a hash which is used by `where` to form the sql statement.  for the block, `first_or_create` uses the options passed to where to create the object if none is found.